# Is there an existing library for shuffling data between Excel, CSV and SQL?

Tags: python, sql, excel, sqlite, csv

I'm writing some code that uses Python to shuffle data around between Excel, CSV and SQLite.

It occurs to me that this may be of use to others, in which case I should generalise it, wrap it up as a library and release it.

I don't want to reinvent wheels, though. Before I embark on this magical adventure, is there already a (python?) library that:

- Exports SQL databases to CSV or Excel. (Relatively easy.)
- Imports CSV/Excel files into SQL, sniffing the data to automatically create tables with columns of the correct types. (A bit more interesting.)

Please provide links to any libraries that already exist (python or otherwise.)

Comment: Most of the SQL are provide the command to export in csv and import from csv. For Excel i have doubt :)

Comment: Adding to that what @Lafada says, you can use xrld/xlwt/xlutils (which parses EXCEL) and SQL database such as PostgresSQL and using some ORM(SQLAlchemy) should serve your purpose. I don't know more direct way than this.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: that's pretty much what my current code does, but as far as I can tell no-one's wrapped it up into a nice package yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the SQLite/CSV interactions, I am the author of a wrapper known as [APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/).  It provides deeper integration between Python and SQLite.  One of the components is a [shell](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/shell.html) that can be used interactively/scripted, as well as programmatically via Python.  It can produce CSV from your database.

More interestingly there is also an `.autoimport` command that given a CSV file with headers will import it into SQLite.  It automatically works out the separators (tab or commas), creates the table and correctly determines the data formats as SQLite's typing is [different](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  For example it won't mess up phone numbers and it can determine what are dates even working out if they are in US, Japanese or standard formats.